# Cross platform... You wish

Tags: code-challenge

Write a program that will produce differing behaviors on as many different platforms as you can. Each differing platform awards one point (including an initial platform, meaning you can't score less than 1*). Mechanisms intended for determining the target/executing platform (e.g. through platform compilation statements or APIs like .NET's Environment.OSVersion.Platform) must not be used. The answer with the highest score wins (where upvotes are the tiebreakers).

For example, consider the following program in the Blub language: `print (1+2)`. If this program were to print `3` on every platform it is compiled and run on, its score would be 1. However, if, for any reason, it were to print `4` on PDP-11s, its score would be 2. Etc. But the following C snippet, for example, is an invalid entry: `#ifdef WIN32 ... #endif`.

---

Definitions/details:

- *Distinct platform:* the combination of a) the hardware architecture b) the OS and its MAJOR version number (e.g. 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 are considered the same OS)
- *Differing behavior:* two behaviors are the same [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) they produce similar side-effects (e.g. creating the same file with the same contents), or if the side-effect are errors of the same kind. For example, if a program segfaults on two distinct platforms, but the segfault message is different on these platforms, this is still considered the same behavior; while a program producing a zero-division error on one platform and a stack overflow (see what I did there? ;) error on another is producing different behavior.
- All undefined behaviors are considered equivalent.
- Program must be invoked in an equivalent manner on all platforms (however; this does mean you can pass command-line parameters if you so desire)

---

* Well, I guess you'd score zero if your program ran on zero platforms. But um... Yeah nevermind.

Comment: Must the program be ran in the same programming language on all platforms? e.g. what if I write a program that prints `1` on Windows and `2` on OSX, with the detail that I run it as a Python script on Windows and a C program on OSX?

Comment: @Geobits I consider OS versions with the same minor version number to be the same platform (same API).

Comment: @Mauris yes, the program must be run in the same language. Also, come to think of it, they should generally take the same command-line parameters (if any), so you can't just provide different arguments on different platforms. Thanks for the great corner-cases so far guys :)

Comment: Do difference browsers count as different platforms for JavaScript?

Comment: @vihan1086 Hmm... Lets say no. That's too easy ;)

Comment: "differing behavior" may need a more precise definition. For example, if a program crashes on multiple platforms, but with different errors, is that differing behavior?

Comment: @RetoKoradi No, I'll say that example is _not_ differing behavior. Edited to include this rule.

Comment: I don't like this challenge. How do you test this on different platforms without having access to them?

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm sure there are a million APIs that are documented to behave differently on different platforms (which is what I expect most solutions will take advantage of), so answers shouldn't be too hard to verify. As for the ones that are bugs, well, we'll burn that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: What if I write a program that prints an uninitialized pointer?

Comment: @someuser that would be undefined behavior on every platform, and undefined behavior == undefined behavior.

Comment: If there are a million APIs that are documented to have different behavior on different platforms and you expect us to use that to our advantage, most of the answers will probably just be "look I found this on the internet, should work, can't test."

Comment: @AlexA. ok, well I guess I'm at a dead end. I suppose there isn't a way to verify solutions as this question stands and I can't think of any way to make that possible for every solution. Does anyone have any ideas? If not, then I guess we'll just have to close this.

Comment: @Jwosty How about you add an underhanded and allwo APIs that are meant to check for plattforms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## C

I will take a stab at it with a textbook-like example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    if (sizeof(&a) > sizeof(int)) {
        printf("foo %d %d\n", *(int *)a, *(long *)a);
    } else {
        printf("bar %d %d\n", *(int *)a, *(long *)a);
    }
}
```

64-bit Platform prints: foo

32-bit Platform prints: bar

Little Endian Platforms: 67305985

Big Endian Platforms: 16909060

So there is at least 4 combinations.

On top of that, some very old platforms has `int` defined as 16-bits. And some platform has `long` defined as 64-bits. So the result will be different as well.

C has been quite platform specific, if you dig deep enough. It is not hard to come up with thousands of combinations (2^10+).

Comment: Isn't this four because of the `\n` vs `\n\r` on *nix and windows?

Comment: I guess that's true if I divert the output into a file on Linux and read it on Windows. But I don't have a Windows C compiler to confirm that natively.

Comment: `printf("\n");` does output `\r\n` on windows (redirecting stdout to a file on windows resulted in a 2 byte file).

Answer (score 3):

### 16/32/64-bit x86/x64 assembly, 16 bytes, 4 combinations

Byte-code:

```
31 C9 41 E2 0A 66 49 41 74 05 0F 00 C0 03 C1 C3
```

Disassembly (16-bit):

```
    xor  cx, cx ;cx=0
    inc  cx     ;cx=1
    loop l1     ;fall through
    dec  cx     ;cx=FFFF
    inc  ecx    ;cx=0000
    je   l1     ;branch taken
    ;...
l1: ret
```

Disassembly (32-bit):

```
    xor  ecx, ecx ;ecx=0
    inc  ecx      ;ecx=1
    loop l1       ;fall through
    dec  cx       ;ecx=0000FFFF
    inc  ecx      ;ecx=00010000
    je   l1       ;branch not taken
    sldt ax       ;detect VMware, VirtualPC, Parallels, etc.
    add  ecx, eax ;conditionally modify ecx
l1: ret
```

Disassembly (64-bit):

```
    xor   ecx, ecx ;rcx=0 (implicit 64-bit zero-extension)
    loopq l1       ;rcx becomes FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, branch taken
    ...
l1: ret
```

It returns:
- CX=0000 in 16-bit mode;
- ECX=10000 in 32-bit non-virtual mode;
- ECX=(random) in 32-bit virtual mode;
- RCX=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in 64-bit mode.